# Macro or formula on Excel to Standardize dates

Tags: vba, excel, date

I really need help on this. I've been looking for an answer for a LONG time but couldn't find it.
In my work, I need to sort a table on Excel using the date present on every line. The problem is that the spreadsheet I use have different layouts of dates as seen below.

```
2/13/2017 4:43:02 AM (M/DD/YYYY)
02/11/2017 05:05 (DD/MM/YYYY)
```

I can't sort it this way because it always read wrongly. What I need to do is to split cells and then concatenate them but this is causing a lot of trouble.

Could you help me check if there's any way to do it automatically, using a macro, or at least using just a formula?

Comment: Are those the only two formats? How do you know the second one is `DD/MM/YYYY`?  The first is obviously `M/DD/YYYY` since there's no 13th month, but how can you tell when it is `DD/MM`? because it has `xx:xx` as time, and not `xx:xx:xx am/pm`?

Comment: Hi, Bruce

I know it because when I try to format the dates, it shows the difference.

Eg. I tried to use the format dd/mmm/aa on both. Here's the result 

2/13/2017 4:43:02 AM
02/nov/17

Tks

Comment: The use of that format shows that Excel is storing the second one as a date, but the first one as a string.  Have you read this data in from a CSV file (or something similar) which has stored all its dates in mm/dd/yyyy format?  If so, the second date should probably be 11 Feb 2017 (because it was in the file as "02/11/2017"), but Excel has assumed that our dd/mm/yyyy date format meant it was 2 Nov 2017 and therefore got it wrong.  If we know how these dates got into your file, we might be able to propose a better way of getting them there which avoids the problems.

Comment: I extracted from a tool we use to handle tickets. It is called Siebel

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the output date you got is in text format, not in date format. Here is the trick to resolve your case to get the output in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format. You can change the format to your desired one.

If text date is in A column, then formula is -

```
=DATE(MID(A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1)+1,4),LEFT(A3,SEARCH("/",A3,1)-1),MID($A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1,SEARCH("/",$A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1)-SEARCH("/",$A3,1)-1))+TIME(HOUR(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))),MINUTE(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))),SECOND(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))))
```

[image]

Hope this helps. Rate if satisfied. :)

Comment: Hi,

Tks for your time =)
I'm facing an issue saying that I had a problem with the formula. Could you help me figure what is wrong?

Comment: Hey can you show me the formula? I am unsure why it gives an error.

Comment: Sure    Here it is  =DATE(MID(A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1)+1,4),LEFT(A3,SEARCH("/",A3,1)-1),MID($A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1,SEARCH("/",$A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1)-SEARCH("/",$A3,1)-1))+TIME(HOUR(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))),MINUTE(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))),SECOND(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))))

Comment: Oh sorry lol

It says that "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it..." It didn't even allow me to insert it =/

Comment: Few things quickly - Your Excel version (mine is 2016), are you using excel or csv

Comment: Also, i checked, this is not the same formula as i gave you in answer. Recopy and paste it properly. Or try writing the formula manually

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: I tried manually this formula     =DATE(MID(A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1)+1,4),LEFT(A3,SEARCH("/",A3,1)-1),MID($A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1,SEARCH("/",$A3,SEARCH("/",$A3,1)+1)-SEARCH("/",$A3,1)-1))+TIME(HOUR(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))),MINUTE(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))),SECOND(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-SEARCH(" ",A3,1))))
     do you know if it works on Excel 2013?